# Expected number of edges in a randomly selected induced subgraph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

Fix a graph $G = (V, E)$, a positive integer $w < n$, and uniformly sample a set of vertices $W \subset V$ where $|W| = w$. How can we compute the expected number of edges in the induced subgraph $G[W]$? My guess is that the expected value will be in terms of some other parameter like the average degree. Are there any known bounds or an exact computation for this problem?

Comment: How do you uniformly sample a set? If that means that every set has a $1/2^n$ probability to be selected then every vertex has $1/2$ and the problem simplifies.

Comment: Assume the size $|W|$ is fixed and uniformly sample over all ${|V| \choose |W|}$ subsets of size $|W|$.

Comment: OK then. In that case, can you find the probability that a vertex $v$ is the induced subgraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, this is simply proportional to the number of edges; for each edge, there is a probability $p = \binom{n-2}{w-2}/\binom nw = \frac{w(w-1)}{n(n-1)}$ that both endpoints end up in $W$, and then the expected number of edges in $G[W]$ is $p|E|$.

To put it differently, if we take $|E(H)|/\binom{|V(H)|}{2}$ (the fraction of possible edges that are actually present) to be the density of a graph $H$, then the expected density of $G[W]$ is equal to the density of $G$ (assuming $w\ge 2$). This follows from the algebraic expression above, but there's also intuition for it that can be turned into a formal argument:

- The density of $G$ is the probability that, if we pick two random vertices $u,v \in V$, there will be an edge $uv$.
- The expected density of $G[W]$ is the probability that, if we randomly pick $W \subseteq V$, then pick two random vertices $u,v \in W$, there will be an edge $uv$.

Comment: I followed a slightly different approach which gave me a different result(of the same order but still). $Pr(u \not\in G[w]) = \binom{n-1}{w}/\binom nw = \frac{n-w}{w} \implies Pr[u \in G[w]) = \frac{w}{n} \implies Pr(e \in G[w]) = (\frac{w}{n})^2$

Comment: @cgss The problem with your approach is that when $uv \in E(G)$, $\Pr[u \in W \land v \in W]$ is not equal to $\Pr[u \in W] \cdot \Pr[v \in W]$: the events $u \in W$ and $v \in W$ are not independent, because a fixed number of vertices must be chosen.

Comment: So for a single vertex the calculation is correct but it breaks for a pair?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: I understand. I knew the problem where each vertex stays in the subgraph with probability p and try to reduce to that. But it makes sense for the second vertex to have lower probability. Thanks for explaining and take my +1.